# Dynamically generating Intent in Dialogflow

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I'm currently dabbling in Dialogflow and have made a functioning test app for my Android device, but am curious how I can expand on this technology. I've only used the UI that's provided on their website but I'd like to access data from an API and use it to dynamically create Intents as well as provide the Intents with Training Phrases.

I haven't been able to find a decent resource (outside of documentation, which I'm having a hard time comprehending) and am hoping someone could direct me or help if they can.

Comment: And you man, are not the only one trying to understand it ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039969/how-to-use-new-dialogflow-sdk-v2-in-android

Comment: Thank you. I'll be following his post.