# How to use new Dialogflow SDK V2 in Android

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, grpc-java

I'm a bit confused about the migration to Dialogflow V2: I have an Android app using https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client (1) that makes voice recognition via "AIService" and request to my Dialogflow Agent V1.

Now with the release of Dialogflow V2, the docs point me to use: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-dialogflow

But I can not see correspondence to AIService in this new SDK for Java... all I've found is this: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2/package-summary.html

My question is: Does actual dialogflow Android client (1) works with V2 Agents?
If the answer is "yes", why Google put this in the docs?:

*Dialogflow's legacy V1 SDKs can be found below. If you are starting a new project please use Dialogflow's V2 and V2 SDKs listed above, as Dialogflow's V1 API will be turned down on April 10, 2019.*

Help will be appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: yes  dialogflow Android client (1) works with V2 Agents. Google put this in the docs becasue now dialogdlow is built with API V2 on Google infrastructure and incorporated the best of Google’s machine learning. Some of API V2’s benefits include Google Cloud Speech-to-Text integration, agent management, and gRPC support.